# Subprocess bash script: command not found

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

The following python script:

```
def run_build(path):
    cmd = path + '/build.sh'
    p = subprocess.call(cmd)
```

The following bash script exec two another scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "${0%/*}"
echo $(./create_env.sh)
echo $(./set_webhook.sh)
echo $(docker-compose up -d --build)
```

create_env.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
PORT=$(comm -23 <(seq 7000 8000 | sort) <(ss -tan | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d':' -f2 | grep "[0-9]\{1,5\}" | sort -u) | head -n 1)
MONGODB_PORT=$(comm -23 <(seq 27017 27100 | sort) <(ss -tan | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d':' -f2 | grep "[0-9]\{1,5\}" | sort -u) | head -n 1)

destdir=$PWD/.env
echo >> "$destdir"
echo "APP_PORT=$PORT" >> "$destdir"
echo "MONGODB_PORT=$MONGODB_PORT" >> "$destdir"
```

The output is:

```
Path: /home/navka/Environments/teststartupservicebot/build.sh
./create_env.sh: line 2: head: command not found
./create_env.sh: line 2: comm: command not found
./create_env.sh: line 2: seq: command not found
...
```

Where is my problem? Thanks!

Comment: Your script doesn't need the command substitutions. Just use `./create_env.sh` in stead of `echo $(./create_env.sh)`, etc.

Comment: This isn't a complete example: what prints `Path: ...`? That's probably where the problem likes. You didn't use the variable `PATH` for your own purposes, did you?

Comment: @chepnerI didn't use `PATH`

Answer (score 1):

I would say your *first* step would be to place:

```
echo $PATH
```

as the first line following the `#!/bin/bash` shebang line in `create_env.sh`, to ensure the path is set up.

Make sure it contains the directory for those executables (probably `/usr/bin`), which you can probably find out by executing (for example) `which comm` or `where comm` from a command line.

If it *doesn't* contain the relevant directory, that explains why it cannot find the executables. In that case, you will need to discover why they're not there.

Perhaps the simplest fix would be to just add something like:

```
PATH="${PATH}:/usr/bin"
```

to your environment setup script. This will ensure the path *does* have the relevant entry.

---

And, as an aside, if those lines in `build.sh` are meant to be cumulative (so, for example, `set_workbook` requires the environment changes made by `create_env`, you should be aware that these are currently run in sub-shells, meaning changes from one will not persist after the sub-shell exits.

That's not necessarily the case as you persist them to a file, which may be read by the subsequent steps.

If you *do* need the changes in the environment for subsequent steps (as opposed to a file), you will need to source them in the context of the current shell, such as with:

```
. ./create_env.sh
```

As I said, this may not be necessary but you may want to look into it, just in case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! `echo $PATH` print `/home/navka/Environments/service-startup-bot/env/bin`, so the path is set up.

Comment: Also, you right, those lines in `build.sh`  are meant to be cumulative and I don't need to change my enviroment variables, only `.env` file

Comment: @KateGurman `PATH` should have *far* more directories that that in it: `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, etc.

Comment: @Kate, the pathis *is* set up but it's almost certainly set up *wrongly* :-) The `comm/seq/head` executables are probably in `/usr/bin` and all you have in the path is that `service-startup` `bin` directory. That's not enough.

Comment: @paxdiablo so, what I need to do?

Comment: @Kate, see the paragraph beginning "Perhaps the simplest fix".